# Why @JsonProperty not work for camel case properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

There is a very simple class:

```
class Price(
    @JsonProperty("YPRICE")
    val yprice: String? = null,

    @JsonProperty("ZPRICE")
    val zPrice: String? = null
)
```

And the following code to serialize to string:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
mapper.writeValue(System.out, Price())
```

The result in console is:

```
{"YPRICE":null,"zprice":null}
```

If changing the property of `zPrice` to `zprice`, then the result changes to:

```
{"YPRICE":null,"ZPRICE":null}
```

And if changing the property of `yprice` to `yPrice`, then the result changes to:

```
{"yprice":null,"zprice":null}
```

It seems that `@JsonProperty` does not work for the camel case properties.

Comment: Not sure how it is in javascript but, in java you might be able to just configure
`mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instruct `ObjectMapper` to generate `JSON` properties based on fields and not based on `getter` methods. You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect` annotation:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
class Price(
```

Since now, in all cases you should see the same result.

Take a look at:

- [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386877/51591)
- [How to ignore "Is' methods with Jackson 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22520436/51591)
- [InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149147/invaliddefinitionexception-no-serializer-found-for-inner-class/55149497#55149497)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But may I know the reason for the case please? Why it shows different result for camel case and not.